# Is movesense magnetometer in NED or ENU reference frame? / How to determine magnetometer reference frame

Tags: sensor, hardware

I can't find an axis diagram for the movesense sensor, nor does it say on the spec sheet on the website - Is the magnetometer in the NED or ENU reference frame? On SO there is an answer that doesn't differentiate between the accelerometer, gyro and magnetometer.

Or if we approach it as a black box, how do I tell what a magnetometer's reference frame is?

I've set it down next to my phone's magnetometer, but as it's not calibrated I'm not sure how to compare. Oriented in the same direction as my phone (text facing upwards), the reading on my phone is: x: 0.1, y: 26.6, z: -31.1 movesense sensor: x: 85.5, y: -12.95, z: 120

If I rotate it 90 degrees towards the east, I get: x: 116, y: 17, x: 124

Comment: Did you read the API (https://www.movesense.com/docs/esw/api_reference/) and download the sample applications ?

Comment: @Hilmar yes, I only see info in the API on how to get the numbers that the sensors are measuring, not on their physical meaning.
The sample applications on that page also don't deal with the magnetometer, but I do have 2 other apps that get raw data from the sensor.